# Recursive directory search loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, recursion, piping

I'm pretty inexperienced with batch scripting, but I need to do the following:

-Recursively Loop through a path input into subdirectories

-For files that match the pattern cls.py and ins.py, execute a command

-Pipe all output to a text file.

For starters, I created a batch file to just try and display the matched file names. Upon execution however, it just echos the if statements a bunch of times.

```
set /p searchdir=Enter Path:
FOR /r %%f in (%%searchdir%%) do (
IF %%~nxf =='ins.py' echo %%~p1
IF %%~nxf =='cls.py' echo %%~p1
)
pause
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's stupid, and constructive is criticism welcome to aid my learning.

Comment: Generally, `Set`ing a variable to `%Path%` is a very bad idea. Reading the built-in help `For /?` and `If /?` is strongly recommended. You might want to take a look at `Start /?` too because `Echo /?` sounds like it may do something different.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].  What command line did you use to call your script?  You're echoing the same thing in both cases and it's the path, if any, to whatever first parameter you supplied on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set /p path=Enter Path:
```

`PATH` is an important system environment variable that you generally don't want to over-write in a script file unless you really know what you are doing.  You may sometimes want to modify it, but that is not the case here.

```
FOR /r %%f in (%%path%%) do (
```

Normally you'd follow the `/r` with the root path and you don't need the double percents around the path variable.  Something like:

```
for /r "%_rootPath%" %%f in (*.py) do @echo %%f
```

But even that's not quite what you want.  Your if statements are really messed up:

```
IF %%~nxf =='ins.py' echo %%~p1
IF %%~nxf =='cls.py' echo %%~p1
```

Whatever %%~nxf expands to can't possibly match the right side of the comparison due to the mismatched quotes.  Anyway, the whole thing is inefficient because your looping over all of the files per directory looking for matches.

One way to do this is to iterate over the files your looking for and then let the dir command find all the directories they are in:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@rem @set prompt=$G

@rem Space delimited list of scripts to run, listed in execution order.
@set _scriptsToRun=ins.py cls.py

@set _root=
@set /p _root=Enter Path:
@if not defined _root @set _root=%CD%
@if not exist %_root% @goto :BadPath
@for %%A in (%_scriptsToRun%) do @call :FindAndExecuteThem "%_root%" "%%A"
@exit /b 0

:BadPath
@set _PATH_NOT_FOUND=3
@echo Path not found: %_root%
@exit /b %_PATH_NOT_FOUND%

:FindAndExecuteThem
@rem @echo %%1==%1
@rem @echo %%2==%2
@for /f %%A in ('dir /b /s "%~1\%2"') do @call :RunIt "%%A"
@rem @for /f %%A in ('where /r %~1 "%2"') do @call :RunIt "%%A"
@exit /b 0

:RunIt
rem @call python.exe %1
rem @call %1
rem @start python.exe %1
```

Note that the above code avoids using multi-line code blocks.  Makes life easier when debugging your work.  Also, you'll probably need a path to the correct version of the python executable.  You can run `start script.py` on some systems, but that's assuming the extension has been mapped to the python.exe file. But you can just call python.exe and skip an extra process startup.

Note that I adopted a convention that script local variables should always have a leading underscore.  This way, when the script dies during development due to some error I've made or because of misuse, it's a simple mater to find and remove all the variables starting with an underscore.  I also use `set prompt=$g` within my scripts during development and usually take it out later. This ties-in with the use of the `@` symbol prefix on every command, which allows me to acquire pin-hole diagnostics by removing a select few of them and not having to wade through an entire scripts worth of spew with echo turned off.  Also, avoid echo on/off in scripts makes them slightly easier to compose with other scripts and there is less risk of modifying the user's environment.

Comment: Great answer, you might want to cater better for an input or matched path containing spaces though.

Comment: I have edited my post, I forgot that path is a cmd reserved word. Looking at your answer, I have been able to search a little more information. functions are defined with the :function notation, @ suppresses console display of execution, /p and /f seem to be object keywords for path and file. for each filename its passing to the find function using the dir command, assigning batch vars to cmd vars (single percentage) and then calling the run it function. Did I understand all of that correctly?

Comment: @Matt_G, `/p` is the prompt option for the `set` command. `/f' is the file option of the `for` command.  In the example above, it is used to process the output stream from the `dir` command.

Comment: @jwdonahue, you'll probably be best advised to at least consider adding them on line `5`: `"%_root%"` and line `11`: `"%~1\%2"` too. _Perhaps on line `9`: %~1 may be better visually after amending line `5`._

Comment: Ok, thanks to @Compo, additional quotes and path not found coverage.  I prefer to error out, rather than trap the user in an entry loop that they can only get out of with Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break.

Comment: @jwdonahue, I've noticed that you've updated your answer, but without incorporating all of the advice I gave in my last comment. If the end user enters `C:\Data Folder` at the prompt, your `%1` and `%2` would be propagated with `C:\Data` and `Folder` respectively; none of your passed `%%A` parameter will be accounted for and your `for` loop will not do what you intended it to. Additionally, you might want to ensure that an existing `%_root%` variable doesn't interfere with your `@if not defined _root` statement.

Comment: @Compo, sigh... yes, I missed a couple more spots.  Hopefully, as the caffeine starts to take effect here, I'll be a little more alert.  Thanks Compo.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example which just `echo`es its results to an output file.

```bat
@Echo Off
:Ask4Dir
Set "searchDir="
Set /P "searchDir=Enter directory to start in [%CD%]: "
If Not Defined searchDir Set "searchDir=."
CD /D "%searchDir%" 2>Nul || GoTo Ask4Dir
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"Where /R . "ins.py" "cls.py" 2>Nul"'
) Do Echo %%~nxA was found in %%~dpA>>"output.txt"
Pause
```

Please study it in conjunction with the information outpt from the following commands entered at the Command prompt: `Echo /?`, `Set /?`, `If /?`, `CD /?`, `For /?`, `Where /?` and `Pause /?`. Depending upon your goal, which isn't clear from your question, you may additionally want to read the output from `Start /?` and `Call /?` too.

Comment: `Where /R` is a nice touch!

Answer (score -2):

```
for /r %A in (c:\windows\win.ini c:\windows\system.ini) Do echo %A
```

CMD is perfectly capable of finding files without your help. Remember `%%A` in batch and `%A` interactively.

What you are doing wrong is your `IF` is comparing a filename to a name enclosed in single quotes. That will never match.

Comment: ACatInLove, because there's a whole lot more than that wrong with the posted script, your response above is currently inadequate to qualify as an answer.

Comment: As the design pattern is rubbish I don't feel the need to contribute to rubbish. Instead I show the correct way.

Comment: I want to find specific files. I know cmd can find all files, but I need to match 'cls.py' and 'ins.py'. If the design pattern is rubbish, maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well LOOK AT MY ANSWER for an example. You need a certain IQ to post here.

Comment: As I said, my answer showed correctly and simply searching for two files in a tree and running a command on each one. When you refuse to read answers and then say something that is untrue. My code will work on any windows system except computers upgraded from NT4. Try it.